# Trying to automate AMI backup of EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have tried automating the backup of AWS ec2 instance using lambda function and triggering a cloudwatch event. I am using a free tier service.

I have scheduled the backup every 5 mins but, After first backup i.e AMI creation, there is no further AMI creation.

Can we create the multiple AMI of the same instance? 
Below is the lambda function used.

Regards
Monika

```js
var aws = require('aws-sdk');  
aws.config.region = 'us-east-1';  
var ec2 = new aws.EC2();  
var now = new Date();  
var date = now.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
var hours = now.getHours()  ;
var minutes = now.getMinutes()  ;
exports.handler = function(event, context) {  
    var instanceparams = {
        Filters: [{
            Name: 'tag:Backup',
            Values: [
                'yes'
            ]
        }]
    };
    ec2.describeInstances(instanceparams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else {
            for (var i in data.Reservations) {
                for (var j in data.Reservations[i].Instances) {
                    var instanceid = data.Reservations[i].Instances[j].InstanceId;
                    var nametag = data.Reservations[i].Instances[j].Tags;
                    for (var k in data.Reservations[i].Instances[j].Tags) {
                        if (data.Reservations[i].Instances[j].Tags[k].Key == 'Name') {
                            var name = data.Reservations[i].Instances[j].Tags[k].Value;
                        }
                    }
                    console.log("Creating AMIs of the Instance: ", name);
                    var imageparams = {
                        InstanceId: instanceid,
                        Name: name + "_" + date + "_" + hours + "-" + minutes,
                        NoReboot: true
                    };
                    ec2.createImage(imageparams, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                        else {
                            var image = data.ImageId;
                            console.log(image);
                            var tagparams = {
                                Resources: [image],
                                Tags: [{
                                    Key: 'DeleteOn',
                                    Value: 'yes'
                                }]
                            };
                            ec2.createTags(tagparams, function(err, data) {
                                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                                else console.log("Tags added to the created AMIs");
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: First question: Why do you wish to create an AMI every 5 minutes? Does your application store data on the server? It is normally recommend to use a datastore such as a database or S3 for storing data. Second question: Do you know that the Lambda function executes every 5 minutes? If so, what error or informational messages are can you see in CloudWatch Logs for the function?

Comment: Creating an AMI takes quite a bit of time and storage space as well. I would rather create [incremental snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html#how_snapshots_work) of the instance every 5 minutes, then manually create an AMI from the snapshot as and when required.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am trying to automate a process for backup so I am checking this function to run every 5 minutes. but it creates only 1 backup and then doesn't . Even when I try runnung the function manually twice. it creates only one backup  and then gives an error for the second time saying the image is already in use. (InvalidAMIName.Duplicate: AMI name AMIBackup_2018-02-18_14-55 is already in use by AMI ami-aff6ecd5)

Comment: @SanchitAnand ...I wish to create a backup everyday and delete it after 5 days.. so that I will have only AMI for last 5 days. Will snapshots serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not being created because it is impossible to have the same AMI name for multiple instances.

Comment: Use this link to achieve this  https://www.bpmtechguru.in/create-ec2-instance-ami-backup-using-lambda-function/

Answer (score 1):

An AMI is the same as a Snapshot, except it can also be used to launch a new instance. An AMI can also contain multiple snapshots (multiple drives).

If your system operates from one volume (the boot volume), having an AMI is an easy way to launch a new instance with exactly the same data. This is normally done to launch an instance with pre-installed software (thus making it in a known state), but can also be used for backup purposes.

Having a snapshot as a backup certainly provides a copy of the volume as at the time of snapshot creation, but to restore the snapshot you actually have to restore the snapshot to a new EBS volume, convert the snapshot to an AMI, then launch an instance from it. (It's a bit harder if it is a Windows boot volume.)

Snapshots and AMIs are incremental, only needing to copy blocks that have been added or changed since a previous snapshot/AMI was created. Thus, they can be very fast to create.

It is not immediately obvious why your code is not functioning correctly. I would suggest adding debug statements before each API call and within the callbacks to obtain more information.

For reference, see also [an EBS Snapshotter in Python](https://gist.github.com/nguyendangminh/6669d8ddf3b09427a949a7869f652cc0).

Answer (score 1):

You can automate your AMI backups. I'm not a Lambda expert, but it can be done -- make sure the IAM roles have the correct permissions and that your functions look for the EC2 Backup and Retention tags. Then you can schedule it through the management console.  Here's an [article](https://www.bluepiit.com/blog/how-to-automate-ami-backups-cleanups-using-aws-lambda-serverless-with-ec2-tags/) with solid details on creating this function.  There are [other ways](https://n2ws.com/blog/how-to-guides/automate-amazon-ec2-instance-backup?nabm=0) to automate snapshots/backups in AWS, if interested.